# Geocortex Essentials Workflow - display map tip at the end of a workflow

Tags: geocortex, geocortex-essentials

I am trying to modify an existing workflow to display a Map Tip. It is a simple zoom and highlight parcel workflow. Currently the result comes up in the Results Panel but I would like it as a Map Tip.

I followed some advice from GE support (invoke Mapi Tip command in External Command Activity) but need some more instructions:

https://support.geocortex.com/essentialsGSCForum?sub-nav=forum&main-nav=essentials&#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=90660000000Gu31AAC

Here's my workflow:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new point feature, which would be like the centre of your polygon (property parcel),  do not pass the fsProperty. The "ShowMapTipResults" expects a point (as if someone clicked on 1 point on the map)         poliart.com

Comment: According to the docs, `ShowMapTipResults` expects the ID of a FeatureSetCollection (https://docs.geocortex.com/essentials/gvh/2.10/commands-help/#/commands/Map%20Widget/ShowMapTipResults). You may try a `SelectFeatures` and set a Collection Name, and pass that same name to `ShowMapTipResults`. But I haven't tried that.